# How to fill a online form automatically using ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, standard-library

I am wondering how I can fill an online form automatically . I am new to ruby development , done this with python .

More Specifically i want to  enter 10 digit pnr no "http://irctc-pnr-status.com/" and then click enter.

Answer (score 2):

Just send as parameter **lccp_pnrno1** your VALUE and then parse response.body

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'     
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://irctc-pnr-status.com/'), 
                               {'lccp_pnrno1'=>'VALUE'})
```

Comment: from where `lccp_pnrno1` parameter you found?

Comment: hey i am new to ruby , just made a shift from c and perl . Interactive ruby is giving false output when i give require 'uri' .                    what is the best source to learn about ruby as a complete that is including using other library and gems . Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: it means that 'uri' is already required. http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Mechanize gem](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). This allows you to perform web requests programatically, including filling in forms and submitting.